# Best way to structure article and issue relationship for CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, taxonomy

So I've got an area of a new WP site I'm building that has a requirement for an Issue and Articles and I'm not entirely sure on how to structure it correctly.

Think of an Issue like a magazine issue. It gets released every few months and has an issue type that needs to specify specific fields for each issue type. An issue has multiple articles in it.

An Article can be one of several article types and likewise has fields based on the article type. An Article is assigned to an issue.

The way I see me doing this is simply have a CPT called Article and have templates for it that handle the various article types. How then would I handle Issues and the relationship they have with Articles? Someone suggested just using the Article CPT and having an Issue type for it, that way I can do the parent/child relationship easily within the same CPT but I'm not sold.

Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be like this:

- Custom Taxonomy Issue
- Custom Post Type Article

You can add custom fields to Taxonomies like described here: 
https://pippinsplugins.com/adding-custom-meta-fields-to-taxonomies/

This way, you get the relation between articles and issues, you can add information about the issue by the custom taxonomy fields, and you can use the taxonomy archive for displaying one issue.

Happy Coding,

Kuchenundkakao